# Smoke script time

Tags: javascript, time, timeout

I am using the following script on my website:

http://demo.web3designs.com/css-jquery-animated-hot-smoke-coffee-tea-effect.htm

How can I edit it so the smoke isn't continuous, but only appears every 20 seconds?

Here's the javascript:

```
if(!$.browser.msie){
        var a=0;for(;a<15;a+=1){setTimeout(function b(){var a=Math.random()*1e3+5e3,c=$("<div />",{"class":"smoke",css:{opacity:0,left:Math.random()*200+80}});$(c).appendTo("#viewport");$.when($(c).animate({opacity:1},{duration:a/4,easing:"linear",queue:false,complete:function(){$(c).animate({opacity:0},{duration:a/3,easing:"linear",queue:false})}}),$(c).animate({bottom:$("#viewport").height()},{duration:a,easing:"linear",queue:false})).then(function(){$(c).remove();b()})},Math.random()*3e3)}
    }else{      
    "use strict";var a=0;for(;a<15;a+=1){setTimeout(function b(){var a=Math.random()*1e3+5e3,c=$("<div />",{"class":"smoke",css:{left:Math.random()*200+80}});$(c).appendTo("#viewport");$.when($(c).animate({},{duration:a/4,easing:"linear",queue:false,complete:function(){$(c).animate({},{duration:a/3,easing:"linear",queue:false})}}),$(c).animate({bottom:$("#viewport").height()},{duration:a,easing:"linear",queue:false})).then(function(){$(c).remove();b()})},Math.random()*3e3)}}}())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $.timer() is what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    // Place your code here;
});

timer.set({ time : 20000, autostart : true });
```

Comment: I set the timer to 5 seconds, but after it starts, it doesn't stop, and there's more smoke every 5 seconds, so I think I have to edit something in the main code too.

Comment: I see.. I tried to edit your code, but it's to messy for me to find out what should be edited. I'm sorry, but this is a start.

Comment: A way would be stopping the function after 5 seconds, then run it again after 20 seconds, and repeat the above, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Try to replace all 'duration:a/4' and 'duration:a/3' for 'duration:5000'; I don't know if this helps, your code is a mess and hard to understand.

Comment: Or set the a var to 5000, instead of: a=Math.random()*1e3+5e3

Comment: I replaced a/3 with 30000, so the smoke appears every 30 seconds, and a/4 with 1300. Thanks